# JavaScript and single-threadedness

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I always hear that JavaScript is single-threaded; that when JavaScript is executed, it's all run in the same global mosh pit, all in a single thread.

While that may be true, that single execution thread may spawn new threads, asynchronousy reqeiving data back to the main thread, correct? For example, when an XMLHttpRequest is sent, doesn't the browser create a new thread that performs the HTTP transaction, then invoke callbacks back in the main thread when the XMLHttpRequest returns?

What about timers--setTimeout and setInterval? How do those work?

Is this single-threadedness the result of the language? What has stopped JavaScript from having multi-threaded execution before the new Web Workers draft?

Comment: javaScript interpreters often shares browsers UI thread

Comment: next time I'm talking about global scope, I'm going to use the term **global mosh pit** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background/7575649#7575649) for a description of how the javascript event queue works, including how it's related to ajax calls.

The browser certainly uses at least one native OS thread/process to handle the actual interface to the OS to retrieve system events (mouse, keyboard, timers, network events, etc...).  Whether there is more than one native OS-level thread is dependent upon the browser implementation and isn't really relevant to Javascript behavior.  All events from the outside world go through the javascript event queue and no event is processed until a previous javascript thread of execution is completed and the next event is then pulled from the queue given to the javascript engine.

Answer (score 6):

`XMLHttpRequest`, notably, does not block the current thread.  However, its specifics within the runtime are not outlined in any specification.  It may run in a separate thread or within the current thread, making use of non-blocking I/O.

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` set timers that, when run down to zero, add an item for execution, either a line of code of a function/callback, to the execution stack, starting the JavaScript engine if code execution has stopped.  In other words, they tell the JavaScript engine to do something after it has finished doing whatever it's doing currently.  To see this in action, set multiple `setTimeout`(s) within one method and call it.

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript itself is single-threaded. It may, however, interact with other threads in the browser (which is frequently written with something like C and C++). This is how asynchronous XHR's work. The browser may create a new thread (or it may re-use an existing one with an event loop.)

Timers and intervals will try to make your JavaScript run later, but if you have a `while(1){ ; }` running don't expect a timer or interval to interrupt it.

(edit: left something out.)
The single-threadedness is largely a result of the ECMA specification. There's really no language constructs for dealing with multiple threads. It wouldn't be impossible to write a JavaScript interpreter with multiple threads and the tools to interact with them, but no one really does that. Certainly no one will do it in a web browser; it would mess *everything* up. (If you're doing something server-side like Node.js, you'll see that they have eschewed multithreading in the JavaScript proper in favor of a snazzy event loop, and optional multi-processing.)

Answer (score 1):

Browser may have other threads to do the job but your Javascript code will still be executed in one thread. Here is how it would work in practice.

In case of time out, browser will create a separate thread to wait for time out to expire or use some other mechanism to implement actual timing logic. Then timeout expires, the message will be placed on main event queue that tells the runtime to execute your handler. and that will happen as soon as message is picked up by main thread.

AJAX request would work similarly. Some browser internal thread may actually connect to server and wait for the response and once response is available place appropriate message on main event queue so main thread executes the handler.

In all cases your code will get executed by main thread. This is not different from most other UI system except that browser hides that logic from you. On other platforms you may need to deal with separate threads and ensure execution of handlers on UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it more simply than talking in terms of threads, in general (for the browsers I'm aware of) there will only be one block of JavaScript executing at any given time.

When you make an asynchronous Ajax request or call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` the browser may *manage* them in another thread, but the actual JS code in the callbacks will not execute until some point after the currently executing block of code finishes. It just gets queued up.

A simple test to demonstrate this is if you put a piece of relatively long running code after a setTimeout but in the same block:

```
setTimeout("alert('Timeout!');", 5);
alert("After setTimeout; before loop");    
for (var i=0, x=0; i < 2000000; i++) { x += i };
alert("After loop");
```

If you run the above you'll see the "After setTimeout" alert, then there'll be a pause while the loop runs, then you'll see "After loop", and only after that will you see "Timeout!" - even though clearly much longer than 5ms has passed (especially if you take a while to close the first alert).

An often-quoted reason for the single-thread is that it simplifies the browser's job of rendering the page, because you don't get the situation of lots of different threads of JavaScript all trying to update the DOM at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language designed to be embedded. It can and has been used in programs that execute javascript concurrently on different operating threads. There isn't much demand for an embedded language to explicitly control the creation of new threads of execution, but it could certainly be done by providing a host object with the required capabilities. The WHATWG actually [includes a justification for their decision not to push a standard concurrent execution capability for browsers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/introduction.html#serializability-of-script-execution).