# condition not working sometimes with gwt

Tags: gwt, web-applications, conditional-statements

I'm having a rare issue in my code, I have a method that makes a very simple validation based on a string variable:

```
private void showNextStep(String psCondition,String poStepName){
    int liCurrentStep=Integer.valueOf(poStepName);
    String lsNextTrueStep=moSteps[liCurrentStep][4];
    String liNextFalseStep=moSteps[liCurrentStep][5];

    if ("Yes".equals(psCondition)){     
        moFrmStepsContainer.getField(liNextFalseStep).hide();
        moFrmStepsContainer.getField(lsNextTrueStep).show();            
    }else{           
        moFrmStepsContainer.getField(liNextFalseStep).show();
        moFrmStepsContainer.getField(lsNextTrueStep).hide();            
    }
}
```

Now, here is the ticky part: if I execute the application without debugging mode, it does the validation right all the time, how ever if don't it always goes to the else block (or at least I think) I tried to use JS alerts (I have a class that calls JS methods) to debug manually and check the valors of the variables; the valors where all right and the validation was also good. This means that only debugging or putting alerts before at the beggining of the IF block it does the validation right, otherwise it always goes to the ELSE, what do you think it could be?

It might be worth mentioning this is a web application made in netbeans 6.9, using the framework GWT 2.1. This application runs in firefox 25.0.1

Thank you!

UPDATE
Here is the code of the event that calls my method

```
final ComboBoxItem loYesNo=new ComboBoxItem("cmbYesNo" + moSteps[liStepIndex][0],"");
 loYesNo.setValueMap("Yes","No");
 loYesNo.setVisible(false);
 loYesNo.setAttribute("parent", liStepIndex);
 loYesNo.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() {
 public void onChanged(ChangedEvent poEvent){
     String lsStepName=loYesNo.getName();
     FormItem loItem=moFrmStepsContainer.getField(lsStepName);
     String liStepNumber=String.valueOf(loItem.getAttributeAsInt("parent"));
     showNextStep((String)poEvent.getItem().getValue(),liStepNumber);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you use the last available GWT (2.5.1)?

Comment: Maybe I can. Do you think it has to do the version?

Comment: Where does `psCondition` come from and when is it set? It smells like a race condition...

Comment: 2.1 is old and maybe there can be an issue already fixed by 2.5.1.

Comment: Js is executed in a single thread, no concurrency.

Comment: Yes David, I guess that could be, psCondition is set by an event, on Changed event of a combo box item. I will post the code right away

Comment: Is the ChangedEvent triggered by a user action or programmatically?

Comment: @Fedy2 It is single threaded but there is an event loop and race conditions are common.

Comment: @DavidLevesque Event are queued and execute by the same thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611145/race-conditions-with-javascript-event-handling

Comment: the changed event is triggered by the user

Comment: In this case that's probably not what I thought. You can try to log the values using `GWT.log()` when running in dev mode. Using javascript alerts may change the behavior of the code because it halts the event loop.