# Using javascript in selenium to listen to AJAX requests

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, selenium

So I know how to use Selenium, and I want to create a chat bot.  However, I do not have access to the source code, and the chat is a custom written page.
This page is making GET requests, and then the site is returning the content I want.
I would like to use Selenium to run javascript (which I know how to do), which either waits for the next GET to come back, or returns whatever the latest GET returned.
At that point I can parse out what I don't need.

I have tried looking for a javascript function to do such, but all I can do is find function that listens to the requests, not the responses.
Thanks!
Note: I will remain active on this page for the next while, so if you need code or such, be sure to ask!

Comment: hi buddy...so you are looking for a selenium function which handles GET requests directly ?? please correct me

Comment: The webpage I am on makes GET requests (I can see them Chrome's developer's tools).  I would like to know what javascript to inject to see what those GET requests return.

Answer (score 0):

how about using fluentWait() mechanism to wait for all ajax:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return  foo;              }     ;

fluentWait(By.xpath(...blablabla...));
//fluentWait(By.cssSelector(...blablabla...));
```

and then able to make js injection like:

```
 public void jsCodeExecution(String jsCode){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(jsCode);
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

or using jsInjection at once. [How does JavaScript handle AJAX responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks for the fluentWait idea, I hadn't thought of that.  My big question, though, is "What is the javascript that will return with whatever the most recent GET request returned?"