# Does Javascript event queue have priority?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

These days, I have read some documents about `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. I have learned that the Javascript is a single thread which will only execute one piece of code per time. At the same time, if there is a event happens, it will be pushed into the event queue and block until appropriate time. I want to know, when many events are blocked waiting to execute at the same time. Do these events have different priorities, so the high priority event will execute before the low ones. Or just a FIFO queue.

```
setTimeout(fn1, 10);
$(document).click(fn2); //will be called at 6ms;
$.ajax({ajaxSuccess(fn3); //async request,it uses 7ms;})

 for () {
    //will run 18ms;
};
```

In the above code, the setTimeout fn1 will happen at 10 ms,click event handler fn2 will at 6ms, ajax callback fn3 will at 7ms, but all the three functions will be blocked until the for loop finish. At 18ms, the for loop finished, so what order does these functions will be invoked.(fn1,fn2,fn3) or (fn2,fn3,fn1)

Comment: *"I have learned that the javascript is a single thread..."* On ***browsers***, yes. Or at least, it used to be. Now we have [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), but the main UI thread in the browser is indeed just one thread.

Answer (score 13):

Work scheduled for the main JavaScript thread is processed FIFO. This includes callbacks from various async tasks, such as `setTimeout` and ajax completions, and event handlers. The only exception is that in the main popular environments (browsers and Node), the resolution callback of a native `Promise` jumps the queue (more accurately, goes in a different higher-priority queue), see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43592450/157247) for details on that.

But leaving aside native promise resolution callbacks:

> but all the three functions will be blocked until the for loop finish. At 18ms, the `for` loop finished, so what order does these functions will be invoked. (fn1,fn2,fn3) or (fn2,fn3,fn1)

The time you give `setTimeout` is approximate, because when that time comes due the JavaScript UI thread may be busy doing something else (as you know); there's also a minimum time required by the (newish) spec, but the degree to which it's enforced varies by implementation. Similarly, you can't *guarantee* that the click event will be queued at 6ms, or that the ajax completion will occur at exactly 7ms.

**If** that code started, and the browser did the 10ms precisely, and the `click` event was queued exactly 6ms in, *and* the ajax request completed at exactly 7ms, then the order would be: `fn2` (the `click` handler), `fn3` (the ajax completion), `fn1` (the `setTimeout`), because that's the order in which they'd be queued.

But note that these are extremely tight timings. In practice, I expect the order the callbacks were queued would be effectively random, because the timing of the `click` would vary, the timing of the `ajax` would vary, etc.

I think this is a better example:

```
var start = +new Date();

// Queue a timed callback after 20ms
setTimeout(function() {
    display("20ms callback");
}, 20);

// Queue a timed callback after 30ms
setTimeout(function() {
    display("30ms callback");
}, 30);

// Queue a timed callback after 10ms
setTimeout(function() {
    display("10ms callback");
}, 10);

// Busy-wait 40ms
display("Start of busy-wait");
var stop = +new Date() + 40;
while (+new Date() < stop) {
    // Busy-wait
}
display("End of busy-wait");

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var elapsed = String(+new Date() - start);
    p.innerHTML = "+" + "00000".substr(elapsed.length - 5) + elapsed + ": " + msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

The order of output will be the two loop messages followed by the 10ms callback, 20ms callback, and 30ms callback, because that's the order in which the callbacks are queued for servicing by the main JavaScript thread. For instance:

```
+00001: Start of busy-wait
+00041: End of busy-wait
+00043: 10ms callback
+00044: 20ms callback
+00044: 30ms callback
```

...where the `+` numbers indicate milliseconds since the script started.

Comment: Nicely explained.  Folks interested in this topic may also want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background/7575649#7575649) about the event queue and other asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 10):

> Does javascript event queue have priority?

Sort of. The event loop is actually composed of one or more event queues. In each queue, events are handled in a FIFO order.

It's up to the browser to decide how many queues to have and what form of prioritisation to give them. There's no Javascript interface to individual event queues or to send events to a particular queue.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/webappapis.html#event-loops

> Each task is defined as coming from a specific task source. All the tasks from one particular task source and destined to a particular event loop (e.g. the callbacks generated by timers of a Document, the events fired for mouse movements over that Document, the tasks queued for the parser of that Document) must always be added to the same task queue, but **tasks from different task sources may be placed in different task queues**.
>
> For example, a user agent could have one task queue for mouse and key events (the user interaction task source), and another for everything else. The user agent could then give keyboard and mouse events preference over other tasks three quarters of the time, keeping the interface responsive but not starving other task queues, and never processing events from any one task source out of order.

Comment: Can you add external references for further reading, re: multiple task sources. Thanks.

Comment: There you go @lukewendling.

Answer (score 2):

FIFO.  There really isn't anything more to say.  You don't get to schedule it.

This can be a bit of a pain when you're looking at multiple timeout operations that could conceivably happen at the same time.  That said, if you're using Asynchronous behaviors you shouldn't be depending on how they get scheduled.

Comment: Expanding a little more: If you're looking to make sure that something exists before you try to anchor an event/handler to it, you can generally use the super-awesomeness of Closures to make multiple events happen serially even if you don't always know what those events are.  If you can't figure that out in your scenario then polling can happen.