# Promise.then Job execution order

Tags: javascript, promise

[The spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) (para 5):

> The PendingJob records from a single Job Queue are always initiated in
>   FIFO order. This specification does not define the order in which
>   multiple Job Queues are serviced. An ECMAScript implementation may
>   interweave the FIFO evaluation of the PendingJob records of a Job
>   Queue with the evaluation of the PendingJob records of one or more
>   other Job Queues.

Does this mean I can't count on the callback supplied to `.then` being evaluated before a callback supplied to `setTimeout` in an otherwise synchronous control flow?

In other words, can I depend on the following printing `one two`.

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('two'));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('one'));
```

Comment: related: [Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915634/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean I can't count on the callback supplied to `.then` being evaluated before a callback supplied to `setTimeout` in an otherwise synchronous control flow?

Yes, that's what it means; the spec doesn't *require* that implementations work that way.

But in practice, the implementations with native `Promise` support I've tested it on have scheduled the `then` callback (a "microtask" from the PendingJobs queue) immediately after finishing the "macrotask" that scheduled it, before other pending macrotasks, even when the pending macrotask was scheduled *before* the microtask. (`setTimeout` and events are macrotasks.)

E.g., in the environments where I've tested it, this outputs `A`, `C`, `B` reliably:

```js
console.log("A");
setTimeout(_ => console.log("B"), 0);
Promise.resolve().then(_ => console.log("C"));
```

But the JavaScript spec doesn't require it.

As [Bergi points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43592505/157247), for user agent environments, the [HTML5 spec covers this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model) in its specification for microtasks and macrotasks. But that's only applicable to user agent environments (like browsers).

[Node](http://nodejs.org) doesn't follow that spec's definition, for instance (not least because its timer functions return objects, not numbers), but Node also gives us `A`, `C`, `B` above, because *(thanks Benjamin Gruenbaum!)* it runs promise resolutions after the `nextTick` queue but before any timer or I/O callbacks. See [his gist](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/9afb9c52facd31484d5fc2e382de44c7) for details.

Comment: Note that in NodeJS promises are run _after_ the _nextTick_ queue but before any timers or IO. Note that the ES spec leaves it to the _platform_ to decide this - so NodeJS and Chrome work _slightly_ differently.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks, very useful. Is the only difference the `nextTick` queue, which Chrome doesn't have?

Comment: Close, but all event handlers for actions that happen the same time (timers, I/O) fire before any nextTick slot. I've made this gist for more info: https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/9afb9c52facd31484d5fc2e382de44c7

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what it means - an other event might fire before the promise callback.

No, that won't happen - while ECMAScript allows it, the [`setTimeout` spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-settimeout) does not.

Comment: I always forget `setTimeout` is not in the spec!

Comment: How/where does the `setTimeout` spec say what happens when a *promise* resolution is queued?

Comment: The following seems relevant: "As such, user agents must instead use the following definition in place of that in the JavaScript specification. These ensure that the promise jobs enqueued by the JavaScript specification are properly integrated into the user agent's event loops." https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-job-queue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant that the whole of the HTML5 spec defines the relation between promise and timeout callbacks, using its concept of micro- and macrotask queues.

Comment: @BenAston: Yes, that looks good -- for user agent environments. Node doesn't follow that spec for its timers (not least that their return values aren't numbers). But it does schedule promise resolution callbacks as microtasks. :-)

Comment: Yeah. Is there an equivalent document for Node.js?

Comment: @BenAston I don't think so, there is no "specification" for that particular implementation. The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) says nothing about promises

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` does not mean that the supplied function will be executed after the provided time. It adds the function to the end of the queue once the delay has elapsed.

It really depends on when your promise resolves, as to the execution of the two statements. In your example, `setTimeout` will add it's callback to the queue ahead of the resolved promise, so you can expect `one two`.