# Using sleep inside recursive setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, settimeout, sleep

I created a function to understand the behavior of the setTimeout() function in javascript. I created a recursive function which keeps calling itself. It worked fine until I added a sleep function inside.
Here's the code.

```
'use strict';

(function iterate(i) {
  var t=setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('timeout ' + i + ' ' + (new Date()));
    sleep(1000);
    console.log('timeout ' + i + ' ' + (new Date()));
    //clearTimeout(t);
    iterate(++i);
  },2000);
})(0);

function sleep(millis) {
  console.log('sleeping...');
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do {
    curDate = new Date();
  }
  while (curDate - date < millis);
}
```

Here's the output when I run this code.

```
timeout 0 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:21 GMT+0530 (IST)
sleeping...
timeout 0 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:22 GMT+0530 (IST)
timeout 1 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:25 GMT+0530 (IST)
sleeping...
timeout 1 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:26 GMT+0530 (IST)
timeout 2 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:29 GMT+0530 (IST)
sleeping...
timeout 2 Wed May 13 2015 12:07:30 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

The difference between two iterate calls should be 2 seconds but it is always sleep_time + delay_time, which in this case is 3 seconds.
Also adding clearTimeout() just before calling iterate(), makes it work normal.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: i think when you put it to sleep, the setTimeout clock also is put to sleep since js is single threaded. Hence 2sec + 1sec(sleep) gives you the 3sec you are experiencing

Comment: Isn't it kind of hard to measure timing to the second when all you're logging is a time with seconds?  I'd suggest you log the time to at least tenths of seconds to see better what is really happening with the timing.

Comment: It should more or less work as you expect when you'd move the `iterate()` call before your sleep. But really, just don't sleep, use a `setTimeout`.

Comment: Ran the code again with a tenth of the current delays. Still the output is similar. It seems to be following the rule that total_delay = sleep_delay + timeout_delay. Here's the output -

Comment: timeout 0 215
sleeping...
timeout 0 317
timeout 1 635
sleeping...
timeout 1 735
timeout 2 35
sleeping...
timeout 2 135
timeout 3 435
sleeping...
timeout 3 535
timeout 4 835
sleeping...
timeout 4 935
timeout 5 235

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background/7575649#7575649) that describes how the JS event queue works may help you understand how `setTimeout()` works.  The article was written about asynchronous Ajax in the browser, but the same principles apply to timers in node.js and the article contains many good references to other articles.

Comment: @NakulMohan - See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8m4gkLet/.  The timing seems to be exactly as expected, sleeps for 1 second, then sets a timer which fires 2 seconds later.  Time for each cycle is 3 seconds which is sleep time + timer time as it should be.  The reason they are sequential rather than in parallel is because the next timer is not set until after the sleep loop finishes.  So you wait 1 second in the loop, then set a timer to fire 2 seconds later.  The only mystery here is why your output is not what others get.

Comment: Yes, same behavior with chrome console. Seems like it's giving unexpected results only with the node.

Answer (score 1):

what is happening here is that you get your code stuck in a while loop for 1 second each time , before the setTimeout is recalled , that is why you get 3 seconds delay .

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (I don't know why I assume that you sleep `sleep(1000)` after both `console.log`):

Are you sure it's correct output? When I run it, it generates expected values:

```
timeout 0 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:16 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:15 sleeping...
VM631:8 timeout 0 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:17 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:6 timeout 1 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:19 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:15 sleeping...
VM631:8 timeout 1 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:20 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:6 timeout 2 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:22 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:15 sleeping...
VM631:8 timeout 2 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:23 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:6 timeout 3 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:25 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:15 sleeping...
VM631:8 timeout 3 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:26 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
VM631:6 timeout 4 Wed May 13 2015 09:16:28 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
```

So we have 1 second delay between `console.log` and 2 seconds of `iterate(i)` delay due to `setTimeout`. It seems to be correct.

Comment: After the second `console.log` , where does it wait one second again?

Comment: This is strange. Did you use clearTimeout() ?. I have commented it.

Comment: That was my mistake. I don't know why I assume that you sleep `sleep(1000)` after both `console.log`s (I edited my answer).
And no, I used your code without any changes, with commented `clearTimeout(t)`.

Comment: Where do you run this code? I checked it in Chrome's console

Comment: I ran it in node with terminal console.

Comment: That's strange, because as far as I'm concerned node js is built on chromes's js runtime

Comment: Ran the code on chrome console. You are right, it works as expected on chrome console. Strange, this question is just producing more questions :(