# ajax async: true statement execution order

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have the following `Ajax`,I want to know when `call back method` of `asynchronous Ajax call start execution`.

```
statement 1;
statement 2;
statement 3;
statement 4;
statement 5;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/includes/unit.jsp?" + params,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    async: true,
    success: function (html) {
        statement 6;
        statement 7;
    }
});
statement 8;
statement 9;
statement 10;
statement 11;
    .
    .
    .
statement 10000;
```

I know `statement 1 to statement 5` will execute in order. As `async: true`, `statement 8;` will execute next, my question is

> when will `statement 6; and statement 7;` execute, will it execute all the statements after the `ajax call` till `statement 10000` then execute `success method`. or at some point it got the response from server while executing `statement 500`, execute `success method` then start executing `statement 501`??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7575589/1592398

Answer (score 0):

First, `async: true` is the default, no need to specify. Statement 6 will execute as soon as a success response comes back from the ajax request. It depends on many factors how much time it will take. Statement 7 will execute right after statement 6.

Comment: so this part or my question is right `or at some point it got the response from server while executing statement 500, execute success method then start executing statement 501`