# ngRepeat through Array, hide other arrays and use next/previous to display

Tags: angularjs

I have an api that has 8 array objects that display fine but my angular code will not hide or show one array at a time. This is just a testing code and will be separated out later. The buttons work because I can see the index go up and down when I click on it but it still displays the whole list.

```
<div class="col-md-2-4"
     ng-class="{'filenum-hide': index  > $index + 1}">

    <ul>
        <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="a in complaints">
            <div class="pull-left">
                {{a.FileNum}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" ng-click="index = index < complaints.length ? index + 1 : complaints.length">Next</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-click="index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
    {{index}}
</div>
```

My outcome looks like this but I want only one list that iterates through the array and only shows case1, then click next, and it will show cw1dpd, etc.

[image]

Response to console.log(data) (sorry I haven't figured out how to angular.toJson log it in a nice format that you can see the nested objects so i snapshotted the console log)

[image]

Error when displaying $scope.complaints = $scope.comp[0];
[image]

Comment: Can you post the JSON?

Comment: @SabarishSenthilnathan, I posted a console.log of the array because the json api looks really messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23292/. From what I understand, you want only one element from the array displayed, and clicking next display the next, and by clicking previous, display the previous element.

I render just the a single `complaints`' element `FileNum`, and render the next and the previous ones by calling `getNext()` and `getPrevious()` function by changing the array index.

**Template:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="clearfix">
       <div class="pull-left">
            {{complaints.FileNum}}
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-disabled="index == 0" ng-click="getPrevious()">Previous</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-disabled="index == items.length - 1" ng-click="getNext()">Next</button>
```

**Controller:** I stored the JSON in `$scope.items` containing just the `FileNum`.

```
$scope.index = 0;

$scope.complaints = $scope.items[0];

$scope.getNext = function (){
  $scope.index = $scope.index + 1;
  $scope.complaints = $scope.items[$scope.index];
}

$scope.getPrevious = function (){
  $scope.index = $scope.index - 1;
  $scope.complaints = $scope.items[$scope.index];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is beautiful. I'll try it in the AM. If I wanted to add a search box to go directly to the filenum, would I just create a $scope.search(FileNum), attach it to a button. How would I set a non-index value to $scope.complaints that's a parameter?

Comment: You'd want to use a `filter`, something like this `$scope.item = $filter('filter')($scope.items, { FileNum: 'case2' });`. Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23295/

Comment: Great. I will replace case2 with a parameter that is designated in a search box.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am anxious to try it.

Comment: Hi Sabarish, I'm having a hard time understanding or translating your  $scope.items in my controller. I know that my controller works because when I use ng-repeat, it allows me to render through the list. If I create another div, like the one in the js fiddle, I try to render {{complaints.FileNum}} with no ng-repeat and nothing shows up. I plan to set the index then do $scope.complaints = $scope.complaints[0] after since I already have my data pulled through a service. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? All you have to do is replace $scope.complaints to $scope.items and the rest of the code can be same as my fiddle.

Comment: Sabarish, thank you again for your help. My JS.Fiddle will not operate as it is pulling data through api, asp.net model but the concept is there: https://jsfiddle.net/3hor1wkg/9/ . I tried over and over to replicate what you have, but I think that my $scope.comp to $scope.complaints is not passing/setting correctly as rendering $scope.complaints does not work either.

Comment: Your fiddle won't work as such because no Service is defined so I have modified it - http://jsfiddle.net/qsL9g4y1/4/. Basically, in place of the Service call I store a dummy data in getComp() function. You're using wrong variable names and that's why the code isn't working. In your getComp() function if you had stored all the result in $scope.comp and got the first element stored in $scope.complaints. The template should have been {{complaints.FileNum}}. Hope this helps. Let me know if not.

Comment: Sabarish, I actually have exactly what you had. I may have sent you the wrong version as I was testing multiple other ways and iddn't realize I needed to send a new link for updated info. I do have $scope.comp in my getComp() service, I do set the index to 0 and I do set $scope.complaints = $scope.comp[0]; I think I may have discovered the error in console.log, but still do not know how to fix it as I do have $scope.index = 0; it says undefined 0. Photo is attached to question. JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/3hor1wkg/9

Comment: Try and define `$scope.comp` outside the function like this: `$scope.comp = [];`

Comment: That resolves the red error but now $scope.complaints is returning undefined in the console.log.

Comment: try and log $scope.comp after $scope.complaints and what does it show

Comment: strange, that returns and array[0] while the inside function returns array[8]. Why would that be if ng-repeat still renders through "a in comp"?

Comment: Ah, this is because it's a AJAX call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081084/angular-scope-not-available-outside-my-function

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Could you possibly show an example for     getng the response value inside the success function of $http which gets called when ajax call executed successfully. I will definitely read those resources and continue learning. This problem will be the death of me!

Comment: Ah yes, in your getComp() function in the service call add `$scope.apply();` after `$scope.comp = data;` That should do the trick.

Comment: I did $scope.$apply and it still is returning undefined for $scope.comp outside of the function. $scope.apply() is not a function it says.

Comment: sorry should be `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: I believe I tried that too. I'm going to take a break from this. Can we please email to try to figure this out? If so, my email is phuongena.vu@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like...

```
<!-- You can set up another if  -->
<div class="pull-left" ng-show='$index > 10 && a.somevalue = "ABC" '>
     {{a.FileNum}}
</div>
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This does not work as it hides everything over 10. I want only one list that iterates through the array and only shows case1, then click next, and it will show cw1dpd, etc.

Comment: It was an example, you can try something that fits into your needs