# JSON data display shows undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to show data using Reddit API. When I display it on alert, it gives undefined as a result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var sample;
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://reddit.com/r/forhire.json', success:
        function(data) {
        sample = data;
    }
    });
    alert(sample);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your ajax request is asynchronous, `sample` *is* undefined at the moment you are passing it to `alert`. The `alert` needs to be inside of your success callback.

```
var sample;

$.ajax({ url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/forhire.json', success:
    function(data) {
    sample = data;
    console.log(sample)
  }
});
```

The asynchronous nature of JavaScript is difficult to understand if you come from a synchronous background. I'd suggest reading [an introduction to asynchronous JavaScript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) or another guide to understand this better. But, I'll do my best to explain the "flow" here. essentially:

1. You declare `sample`
2. You initiate an Ajax request (which uses an [XMLHTttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)) which is asynchronous by default. The browser begins this request in the background, noting the `success` callback provided to it, and continues on its merry way to the next statement. While this seems terrible, *it's actually wonderful!* because a single threaded JavaScript environment can dispatch multiple actions without having to worry about blocking execution.
3. Your `alert` triggers with the current value of `sample` which `undefined`
4. The ajax request (which has been going on in "the background") finishes, since you provided a `success` callback, it invokes it with the returned data
5. `sample` (which is available in the scope of your callback because you defined it in a parent scope) is now assigned to the value of `data`

If you'd like to understand a little bit more about what is going on behind the scenes, i'd recommend this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575649/1048479).

Comment: Can you explain why? I come from a C/C++ background. The variable sample's scope is global.

Comment: Certainly, I gave it a shot. There's a lot of information on the subject available so i'd recommend looking through a few resources instead of trusting me. It can take a little while to wrap your head around but it will become second nature very soon. I'm still wrapping my head around pointers and memory management so you are leagues ahead of me ;)