# synchronous method angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have cell in grid that contains number of users per each company, this number comes from typescript method  getNumberOfUsers() ,this method call Back-End web service return  number of users .
Issue: all cells displayed 0, Although getNumberOfUsers()  print number of user   in console

```
 <tr>
   <td>
     {{ getNumberOfUsers() }}
   </td>
 </tr>
```

component ts file

```
getNumberOfUsers(): number {
  let NumUser=0;
  this.callServices.getUserCount().subscribe((res: any) => {
    NumUser = JSON.parse(res._body).numberOfUser;
    Console.log(“NumUser=”+ NumUser)
  },
    (err) => console.error(' getUserCount::err==' + err)
  );

  return NumUser;
}
```

callService file

```
getUserCount(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/ getUserCount);
}
```

I want to make synchronous method

Answer (score 0):

Async method doesn't work in synchronous way. Recommend you to read up on [How does JavaScript handle AJAX responses in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575649/2435473)

You could consider using using `async` pipe in this case to display a value filled by async nature.

Change your factory method to return `json` from it.

```
getUserCount ():Observable<any>
{
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/ getUserCount).map(data => data.json())
}

//change getNumberOfUsers to return getUserCount Observable 
getNumberOfUsers(): Observable<any>{
    this.callServices.getUserCount();
}
```

**Html**

```
{{ (getNumberOfUsers() | async)?. numberOfUser}}
```