# Execute multiple callbacks from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of callbacks, so that each takes another callback that gets executed when job is done. Example:

```
var queue = [
    function (done) {
        console.log('Executing first job');
        setTimeout(done, 1000); // actually an AJAX call here
            // I can't call abort() for the request
    },
    function (done) {
        console.log('Executing second job');
        setTimeout(done, 1000);
            // also AJAX call here
            // it is made from a third-party library that I can't change
            // this means that I can't call abort() on it
    },
    function (done) {
        console.log('Executing third job');
        setTimeout(done, 1000);
    },
    function (done) {
        console.log('Executing fourth job');
        setTimeout(done, 1000);
    } // and so forth
];

var proceed = true;

(function dequeue() {
    var fn = queue.shift();
    proceed && fn instanceof Function && fn(dequeue);
})();
```

It is fine with me except that to speed up everything I better fire up, say, four callbacks at once while still being able to stop further execution by changing the `proceed` flag from elsewhere. How do I do that?

I use most current version of jQuery on this project, so if there is anything in the library that can help accomplish this task, I would use it. Everything happens in a browser.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so executing them in parallel won't speed anything up.

Comment: @Blender, you're right except that first A in AJAX stands for asynchronous which suggests that we still can have something done in sort of background thread

Comment: @sanmai even though ajax is asycn, at at point of time only one javascript context will be executed

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm fine with that; see updated question

Comment: @sanmai: I think AJAX does not imply multi-thread in JS. That's up to the server and the browser. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914161/ajax-multi-threaded

Comment: Can you explain your *exact* situation? Oversimplifying the code is going to get counterproductive very quickly.

Comment: Your question is not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @elclanrs If I'd fired, say, a hundred of AJAX requests, they'll all get executed at some point, but the problem is that if I can't call `abort()` on these requests so to stop everything by users' request, I have to execute these request one by one to be able to stop everything at once

Comment: @sanmai: Why can't you abort them?

Comment: @Blender, If I could abort them, there will be no question; please try using your imagination

Comment: Voting to close as the question is not clear enough for anyone to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 see my answer; still I'm looking for more or less "reinvent the wheel"-ish way to do these kind of things with, maybe, `$.Deferred()`

Comment: @sanmai: Not helpful at all. As I said before, oversimplifying or overgeneralizing your situation will make things more difficult than they need to be. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg6r/

```
var queue = [];
// let's think we have a thousand of jobs
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    (function(jobNumber) {
        queue.push(function (done) {
            console.log('Started job '+ jobNumber);
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('Finished job '+ jobNumber);    
                done();
            }, 1000);
        });
    })(i);
}

var proceed = true;

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Full stop called after 10 seconds');
    proceed = false;
}, 10000);

queue.depth = 0;
queue.maxDepth = 4;

(function dequeue() {
    while (queue.depth < queue.maxDepth) {
        queue.depth += 1;
        var fn = queue.shift();
        proceed && fn instanceof Function && fn(function() {
            queue.depth -= 1;
            dequeue();
        });
    }
})();
```